# Jquery for each loop create a table

Tags: jquery, loops

How can I create a table in the first loop  `$.each(data, function (i, dataitem) {}` and insert the second loop  ( `$.each(dataitem, function (i, item) {}` ) in it.

```
if ($.trim(data)) {
    $.each(data, function (i, dataitem) {
        $.each(dataitem, function (i, item) {
            var $tr = $('<tr>').prepend(
                    $('<td>').text(item.productstore.products.name),
                    $('<td>').text(item.quantity);
            ).prependTo('#output');
        });
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

Right now it only outputs :

```
<div id="output">
    <tr><td>product</td><td>qty</td></tr>
    <tr><td>product2</td><td>qty2</td></tr>
</div>
```

I can't figure out how to wrap it in `<table></table>`

Comment: Just like you are creating the $tr in the inner loop, you create the $table in the outer loop, or outside both loops, and append to it.  What is confusing you about this?

Comment: Cant you just change `<div id="output"></div>` to `<div><table id="output"></table></div>`

Comment: To limit the number of times you change the DOM, you really want to build the table as a dom fragment and then append it.

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen I have multiple objects in data and I need a table for each of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jQuery constructor to construct DOM elements on the fly. Just like you're doing with $(''). Simply do the same with the table. Try the below.

```
if ($.trim(data)) {
  $.each(data, function (i, dataitem) {
    // Table element being constructed.
    // Not yet inserted into the DOM. 
    var $table = $("<table>");
    $.each(dataitem, function (i, item) {                              
      var $tr = $('<tr>').prepend(
              $('<td>').text(item.productstore.products.name),
              $('<td>').text(item.quantity),

              ).prependTo($table);
    });
    // Insert the constructed table into the DOM.
    $table.prependTo("#output");
  });
}
```

Comment: Is there any way I could add a class to all tables except first one? And is it possible to make another loop inside a `<td>`?

Comment: Why not just use an if-statement on `i` to check if it is the last one (since you're prepending, as opposed to appending). It's just basic stuff. EDIT: Also, in case you are unaware, you can call `$table.addClass("some-class");` on the `$table` object.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will try. Can you point me in the right direction in order to add another loop into a <td>? Inside that td I need each element to concatenate as a text.

Comment: Do you need a loop for that? You can probably get away with using [String.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) and using the resulting string as a parameter to `$('<td>').text()`.

Comment: I need to loop through multiple elements. It's an array of the item object. I want to concatenate `item.array.name`

Comment: How about using a [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)?

Comment: Does it work with a json array? It returns undefined

Comment: Probably not, but you can massage the data a little bit with a call to `$.map()` first. The answer from Taplar uses that function so you can take it as an example. Just extract the strings from the object.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//prepend all the tables after they have been created so there is a single
//change to the DOM
$('#output').prepend($.map(data, function(dataitem, i) {
  //return a table with all the rows appended to it
  return $('<table>').append($.map(dataitem, function(item, i) {
    //return a row with both the cells appended to it
    return $('<tr>').prepend(
      $('<td>').text(item.productstore.products.name),
      $('<td>').text(item.quantity);
    );
  }));
}));
```